# Php get Excel file via sftp

Tags: php, ftp, sftp

I'm a complete noob in PHP and tried to solve my problem via the forum here but without luck!
I have a little download script that downloads a .csv file from a FTP server. That server is changed to a sftp server.

The problem I'm facing is that I'm unable to connect to the server anymore and just can't see why my code won't work. Any help greatly appreciated.

My old script:

```
function downloadFile(){
    $ftp_server = "feed.onftpsite.com";
    $ftp_username="1234";
    $ftp_userpass="1234";

    $conn_id = ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_server);
    $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);
    ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
    $server_file = "map/file.csv";
    $localfile = "some_other_file.csv";
    if (ftp_get($conn_id, $localfile, $server_file, FTP_ASCII)){
        echo "Successfully downloaded $localfile.";
    }else{
        echo "Error in downloading $localfile.";
    }
    ftp_close($conn_id);
}
```

Now I tried to change this to a sftp format:

```
function downloadFile(){
    $ftp_server = "feed.onftpsite.com";
    $ftp_username="1234";
    $ftp_userpass="1234";

    $conn_id = ssh2_connect($ftp_server, 22);
    $login_result = ssh2_auth_password($conn_id, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);
    ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
    $server_file = "map/file.csv";
    $localfile = "some_other_file.csv";

    if (fopen($conn_id, $localfile, $server_file, FTP_ASCII)){
        echo "Successfully downloaded $localfile.";
    }else{
        echo "Error in downloading $localfile.";
    }
    //ftp_close($conn_id);
}
```

Why doesn't above code work?

Comment: What actually happens when you run your new code? Do you get any error messages? What do they say?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the error is, but I can recommend trying [phpseclib](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib). Otherwise try providing an error message from the code above.

phpseclib is very simple to use, for exammple:

```
$sftp = new \phpseclib\Net\SFTP($host);
if (!$sftp->login($user, $password)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
$sftp->chdir('textfiles/');

$file = $sftp->get('example.txt');
```